# Preferred way of declaring Controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

There are few available ways of [defining a controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) in AngularJs. Concretely:

1. "attach to `$scope`" syntax
2. "controller as" syntax
3. `controller()` function

Code showcase of the above:

```
// 1)
ng-controller="MyControllerFn"

// 2)
ng-controller="MyControllerFn as myCtrl"

// 3)
myModule.controller("myCtrl", MyControllerFn);
// or
myApp.controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {

}]);
```

Of course, each of those has it's pros and cons. Currently I'm using option 1). My problem is, I don't know if I'm not missing out anything in long term, now that new "controller as" syntax is available for me to use. Our project is quite large and I can't see myself rewriting everything to new syntax in a year or so, just because old one became deprecated. I'd rather slowly make a transition now, and write new code in "the good way" starting today.

Few PROS and CONS:

1)

- (good) less boilerplate comparing to 3), as autodiscovery of controllers takes care of declaration for you when it encounters `ng-controller` directive
- (bad) supports proper DI: `MyControllerFn.$inject = [...]`
- (bad) harder to navigate in controller's inheritance tree

2)

- (good) controller alias makes it clear which scope variables refer to
- (good) cleaner controller syntax because of assigning variables to `this`
- (good) seems to be improving Tooling support (IDEs)
- (bad) prone to error of adding too many things to scope, for instance: `this.arr = ...; // array of 1mln items'

3)

- (neutral) minification done right (well, this can be done with `$inject` property)
- (bad) more verbose syntax which can be completely avoided by autodiscovery

Ok, so am I missing anything? Perhaps I don't see something obvious, as I moved to 1.2 just recently?

---

### = EDIT

To make it clear, there is a difference between binding and declaring a controller. First two demonstrated options are about binding a controller to DOM, whereas third one is about explicitly declaring it in angular module. An opposition to the latter would be allowing Angular to go through the DOM and discover controller automatically, which is my preferred way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

To get things straight:

First of all, there are two distinct things that need to be accomplished:

1. Define the implementation of the controller (i.e. the function that will be "`new`ed" to create an instance of the controller).
2. Bind a controller to a DOM element (i.e. say "this part of the view is controlled by an instance of the controller known as 'someCtrl'").

Then it is Angular's job to link things together:

1. I see element in the view.
2. I see that element x is bound to controller y.
3. I find the function that is registered as the implementation of the controller named y.
4. I create a new instance of the controller using that function.
5. I pass the new controller instance to the element (i.e. evaluate each Angular expression found on the element and its descendants against that controller-instance - unless a subtree of the view is bound to another controller-instance etc).

---

(1) and (2) are ways of binding a controller to a DOM element.
Additionally to them, there is also the directive's `controller` property and the `ngRoute`'s `controller` property, which you don't mention at all.

(3) is a way of registering the controller's implementation with Angular's DI (which takes care of instantiating a controller bound to a specific element.
In that sense, auto-matching the controller implementation by the name of the function (what you refer to as (autodiscovery) is an alternative to (3), so let's name it (4).

According to the above, (1) and (2) are not alternative approaches to (3) and (4), but they are both needed and complement each other.

---

From the above features, "autodiscovery" is the one I would want to rely the least on.
It feels hacky/not very "robust" and it's purpose is to reduce the required code for quickly putting together small prototypes or examples, not to be used in large scale, production applications.

From Angular's **[Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)**:

> **NOTE:** Although Angular allows you to create Controller functions in the global scope, this is not recommended. In a real application you should use the `.controller` method of your Angular Module for your application [...]

---

IMO, the real debate is about `controller` vs `contoller as`.

Here are some considerations:

1. The `controller as` feature was a new feature and maybe still under evaluation. It is probably here to stay, but I wouldn't bet all my money on that.
2. In the `controller as` syntax, there is no actual `$scope` (i.e. a `Scope` object, descendant of the `$rootScope` etc). This fact has some implications regarding how you perform some `$scope`-specific stuff, e.g. registering listeners with `$on()`, `$watch`ing over properties etc.
3. The `controller as` syntax might improve maintainability/readability of the views, since it is explicit what controller each property refers to - it avoids cases of a property being available through prototypal inhertance, being overwritten etc. On the other hand, the absense of prototypal inheritance poses limitations on how data could be propagated.

---

That said, I have a slight preference for the `controller` syntax, as I find the utilities offered by `$scope` useful and I haven't found any usecase in my projects that would make the `controller as` syntax preferable.

Comment: Well, I'll have to argue a bit :-) I do understand the concept of `declaration` and `definition` in programming languages, in Angular likewise. I know that 1 and 2 are methods used for binding, but my question was about choosing one over the other. 3 & 4, agreed, they are complementary but definitely `NOT NEEDED` because of auto matching. For me less robust is exactly 3 & 4, because I need additional code to make it work (violation of convention over configuration). As to the last question - are you sure that `this` is not in reality a `$scope` when using `controller as` syntax?

Comment: 1) Your question looked like you consider (3) to be an alternative approach to (1) and (2) (which clearly isn't; it's a totally different thing). As (4) I refer to the auto-discovery (not your 3b). Either (3) or (4) **is** absolutely necessary ((4) is your "autodiscovery" - so you need to either rely on auto-discovery (4) or explicitly register the controllers (3) - but one of the two is absolutely necessary). Additonal code does not mean less robust (and additional code of one line isn't that much of an overhead imo).

Comment: Have you considered the implications of a 3rd party library defining a function with the same name as your controller in the global scope ? Auto-discovery is more susceptible to error (and therefore less robust). And finally, yes, I am very sure that `this` is not a `$scope`.

Comment: Sorry, for the long comments, but there were many topics to cover :) As I said, I consider auto-discovery to **not** be "production ready", but that is a personal judgement and others may think otherwise (I will look for more "hard evidence to back up my opinion and update if I find anything). For me the real dilema is `controller` vs `controller as`. I mentioned the differences there are (and my considerations) - as I said I don't have strong feelings for either (but I use and slightly favor the former).

Comment: Yes, I realized that my list of 1..3 could have been perceived as alternatives, which was not my intention. Will fix that. Name collisions are very unlikely and I wouldn't sacrifice readability and easy of maintain my code for the fear of running into problems there. I really love "auto discovery" and I still can't find anything against it :)

Comment: You do realize that the "unreadability" and "unmaintainability" you refer to is no more than half a like long: `.controller('someCtrlName', someCtrlFunc);` (Not to mention that it is much more maintainable this way as your app grows.)

Comment: BTW, I updated my answer with a quote from Angular's Developer Guide, which refers to auto-discovery...

Comment: @ŁukaszBachman: Did you take a look at the updated answer ? Still not convinced ? :)

Comment: I am still to evaluate few things :) This note from AngularJs team does not convince me, see this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/UF8Np3B0Lr4
I agree with the statement, that possible namespace pollution is simply too vague of a reason.

Comment: I read that thread and I wonder how did you get the impression that polluting the global namespace is a non-issue. Everyone seems to agree on that (except for one guy). So, one random guy knows better than: lots of random guys, several not-so-random guys (in that thread are a few Angular "legends") **and** the Angular team itself ! Wow, you must be one hell of a confident fella :) Anyway, I am all into doing what your got tells you (inspite everyone else's telling you otherwise) - it often involves some "learning the hard way" but it is fun !

Comment: But, polluting the global namespace is **not a good practice**. _not a good practice_ does not mean it is a bug, does not mean it will break your app tomorrow, does not mean a kitten will die. It just means that it may (or may not) make your app less maintainable, less extensible and more work for your future self (or others). But in the end it's your call :)